# Tic Tac Toe game not showing from website

Tags: reactjs, tic-tac-toe

I have copied the below code from react.dev (https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) to VS Code to see what the tic-tac-toe game looks, but there is nothing showing on the web browser or VS Code preview window. I am new at react and trying to see it before I can do the exercise. I would like to know why nothing is displaying.

```
index.html

{
  "name": "react.dev",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

```
App.js

import { useState } from 'react';

function Square({ value, onSquareClick }) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}

function Board({ xIsNext, squares, onPlay }) {
  function handleClick(i) {
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    if (xIsNext) {
      nextSquares[i] = 'X';
    } else {
      nextSquares[i] = 'O';
    }
    onPlay(nextSquares);
  }

  const winner = calculateWinner(squares);
  let status;
  if (winner) {
    status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
  } else {
    status = 'Next player: ' + (xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
        <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
        <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
        <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
        <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
        <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
        <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default function Game() {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([Array(9).fill(null)]);
  const [currentMove, setCurrentMove] = useState(0);
  const xIsNext = currentMove % 2 === 0;
  const currentSquares = history[currentMove];

  function handlePlay(nextSquares) {
    const nextHistory = [...history.slice(0, currentMove + 1), nextSquares];
    setHistory(nextHistory);
    setCurrentMove(nextHistory.length - 1);
  }

  function jumpTo(nextMove) {
    setCurrentMove(nextMove);
  }

  const moves = history.map((squares, move) => {
    let description;
    if (move > 0) {
      description = 'Go to move #' + move;
    } else {
      description = 'Go to game start';
    }
    return (
      <li key={move}>
        <button onClick={() => jumpTo(move)}>{description}</button>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="game">
      <div className="game-board">
        <Board xIsNext={xIsNext} squares={currentSquares} onPlay={handlePlay} />
      </div>
      <div className="game-info">
        <ol>{moves}</ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```
index.js

import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./styles.css";

import App from "./App";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```
styles.css

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h5 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

code {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

ul {
  padding-inline-start: 20px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}

.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.status {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.game-info {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```
package.json

{
  "name": "react.dev",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

I have tried to check if the files are connected properly, since I am new at this I am not really sure. I am expecting to see the tic-tac-toe grid and all the rules for the game showing on the web browser or preview window on VS Code

Comment: You've pasted `package.json` twice while `index.html` is missing.